# Download Android v10 source through git

Tags: git, android-source

I want to download the complete android v1.0 sources. Is the source available [here](http://source.android.com/source/index.html) what I am looking for? Or is it some newer version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget that you do not need android source code to be able to develop application with. SDK is enough and designed for.
**git is not enough**, you need **"repo"** to be able to download a particular version of android see http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
By using repo you will need to precise the branch name . it's a main label for a particular version see  http://source.android.com/source/code-lines.html
Starting with cupcake (version 1.6, 1.0 not available here) you'll get main tags and version names at http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html
To browse the code you may visit https://android.googlesource.com.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Linux for getting sources. Just follow these steps:
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html